# How to insert key value pair in an existing array object using php/laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, object

My Code:

```
$finalArray = json_encode($loanTypeCount);
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"Salary","y":"6"},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1"}]
```

Desired Output:

```
[{"name":"Salary","y":6, "selected": true},{"name":"Emergency","y":1, "selected": true}]
```

Inserted `"selected": true` key value pair. What is the way to do it in laravel/php?

Comment: Decode, add value to array/object, re-encode. Or do it before you encode it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a Collection instance, you can do it with `map()`

```
$loanTypeCount->map(function($loan) {
    $loan->selected = true;
    return $loan;
});
```

Comment: If your desired result is a JSON encoded string, end with `->toJson()`.

Comment: @Dan he starts with (mostly) a collection and json_encode it in his question.

Comment: what if I want to assign a value from the database to the $loan->selected ? I want something $loan->selected = $loan->loan_type; I tried this already but it returns null.

Comment: @Eli it should work, unless the $loan->loan_type is null in your database

Answer (score 1):

Based on [N69S' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271976/8394877), here an example starting with a JSON encoded string instead of a collection instance and ending with a modified one.

```
$json = '[{"name":"Salary","y":"6"},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1"}]';

$arr = collect(json_decode($json, true))
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        $item['selected'] = true;

        return $item;
    })
    ->toJson();
```

Comment: what if I want to assign a value from the database to the $loan->selected ? I want something $loan->selected = $loan->loan_type; I tried this already but it returns null. – 
Eli

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with pure php:

```
$json = '[{"name":"Salary","y":"6"},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1"}]';

$obj=json_decode($json);
$obj[0]->selected = true;
$obj[1]->selected = true;

$newJson = json_encode($obj);
//[{"name":"Salary","y":"6","selected":true},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1","selected":true}]
```

Alternatively with foreach:

```
$json = '[{"name":"Salary","y":"6"},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1"}]';

foreach($obj=json_decode($json) as $key => $item){
  $obj[$key]->selected = true;
}

$newJson = json_encode($obj);
//[{"name":"Salary","y":"6","selected":true},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1","selected":true}]
```